# android.support.v4.app.Fragment.mFragmentManager' on a null object reference

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigationview

i have the follow lines of code that I am using to create a navigationview to load fragments and this android application. I am getting the error: **android.support.v4.app.Fragment.mFragmentManager' on a null object reference**. I created the fragments already and the navigationview works.

```
public void selectDrawerItem(MenuItem menuItem){

    Fragment fragment = null;
    Class fragmentClass = null;

    switch(menuItem.getItemId()){
        case R.id.nav_show_all_events_activity:
            fragmentClass = AllEventsFragment.class;
            break;
        case R.id.nav_whats_hot_today_activity:
            fragmentClass = WhatsHotFragment.class;
            break;
    }

    try {
        fragment = (Fragment) fragmentClass.newInstance();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.flContent, fragment).commit();

    menuItem.setChecked(true);
    setTitle(menuItem.getTitle());
    mDrawer.closeDrawers();
}
```

Comment: Your way of creating the `fragment` is somewhat weird. Are you sure that `fragment` is not null?

Comment: Yeaa, you don't need reflection to create your Fragment, just call `fragment = new AllEventsFragment()` or `fragment = new WhatsHotFragment()`

Comment: I tried that at my first attempt and it failed (`fragment = new AllEventsFragment()`). I am sure that`fragment` is not null.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have only 2 MenuItems in your menu ? If there are more, you will end up with a `null` fragment. You could add a 'default' case to your switch statement:

```
switch(menuItem.getItemId()){
    case R.id.nav_show_all_events_activity:
        fragmentClass = AllEventsFragment.class;
        break;
    case R.id.nav_whats_hot_today_activity:
        fragmentClass = WhatsHotFragment.class;
        break;
    default:
        return;
}
```

That should ensure fragment will not be null.

Comment: thank you forgot to add `return`. still does not work thou

Answer (score 0):

I analysed the code and wondered why the previous method did not work. I found a minor issue regarding the imports i used. I used the following `import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;` import in `main_activity`. Saw that i was using `import android.app.Fragment;` in the classes `AllEventsFragment` and `WhatsHotFragment`, of which i changed the imports to `import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;` Thank you for your help.
Final version below:

```
public void selectDrawerItem(MenuItem menuItem){

    FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
    Fragment fragment;

    switch(menuItem.getItemId()){
        case R.id.nav_show_all_events_activity:
            fragment = new AllEventsFragment();
            break;
        case R.id.nav_whats_hot_today_activity:
            fragment = new WhatsHotFragment();
            break;
        default:
            return;
    }

    transaction.replace(R.id.flContent, fragment);
    transaction.commit();

    menuItem.setChecked(true);
    setTitle(menuItem.getTitle());
    mDrawer.closeDrawers();
}
```